# OnInfoListener is never called

Tags: android

I'm trying to listen to OnInfoListener of a mediaplayer I've created to get when buffering starts and ends.

For some reason the event never fires.

This is my initializing code

```
private void initPlayer(Surface s){
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setSurface(s);


    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(file_url);
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        OnError(PLAYER_ERRORS.player_not_loaded, e.getMessage() + "");
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        OnError(PLAYER_ERRORS.player_not_loaded, e.getMessage() + "");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        OnError(PLAYER_ERRORS.player_not_loaded, e.getMessage() + "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        OnError(PLAYER_ERRORS.no_connection, e.getMessage() + "");
    }
}
```

And this is my listener

```
    @Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {


    if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START)
    {
        OnEvent(PLAYER_EVENT.buffering_start);
    }
    else if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END)
    {
        OnEvent(PLAYER_EVENT.buffering_end);
        OnGotDuration(getDuration());
    }

    return what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START || what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END;
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: Is file you are trying to play is local?

Comment: No, it's an HLS file streaming from a 3rd party server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well apparently it's a known bug in Android. 
When playing HLS stream it's just never calls OnInfoListener or OnBuffering.

Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42767) for more details

My so called solution was to create a thread now runs along side of the player, and checking its progress from time to time to determine if the playback is stopped - assuming that means the player is buffering.

Here's my code for whom ever wants it

```
    private class BufferingThread extends Thread{

    WeakReference<NewDefaultPlayer> player;
    long currentPos, lastSecond;
    boolean isBuffering, alreadyBuffering;
    private Object locker = new Object();

    public BufferingThread(NewDefaultPlayer player) {
        this.player = new WeakReference<NewDefaultPlayer>(player);
    }

    private Runnable BufferStart = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            player.get().OnEvent(PLAYER_EVENT.buffering_start);
        }
    };

    private Runnable BufferStop = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            player.get().OnEvent(PLAYER_EVENT.buffering_end);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        while(true)
        {
            synchronized (locker) {
                currentPos = player.get().getCurrentPosition();
                isBuffering = currentPos == 0 ? true : currentPos <= lastSecond;
                lastSecond = (int) currentPos;
                if(alreadyBuffering){
                    if(!isBuffering)
                    {
                        if(player.get().getPlayerState().equals(PLAYER_STATES.IS_PLAYING))
                        {
                            alreadyBuffering = isBuffering;
                            TvinciSDK.getMainHandler().post(BufferStop);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if(isBuffering){
                        alreadyBuffering = isBuffering;
                        TvinciSDK.getMainHandler().post(BufferStart);
                    }
                }
                try {
                    sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

//Stop the thread if the user has stopped the video
private void handleBufferingWorkaround(boolean work){
    if(bThread == null)
        bThread = new BufferingThread(this);
    if(work){
        if(!bThread.isAlive())
            bThread.start();
    }
    else if(bThread.isAlive())
    {
        bThread.interrupt();
        bThread = null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps