# how to find out when the user had switched on the gps and wifi in android?

Tags: android

i have made an android application in which i need user's gps and internet connection. 
Now if the user has not switched any of the above on, then i show a message to the user to switch on their gps and internet.

Once the user reads this message and switches his gps and internet on, i need to reload my activity.
To do this i need to capture the event when the user has switched on his gps/wifi and then reload my activity.

How do i achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

BroadCastReceiver &
NetworkManager will solve your problem.
This will help you..
[Detect 3G or Wifi Network restoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503561/detect-3g-or-wifi-network-restoration)